# createReadStream pipe not working in electron 1.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

createReadStream pipe not working in electron 1.6. It was working for 1.3 version. But now when i updated the version of electron, it not working. Please refer the code below.

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'});        

var rs = fs.createReadStream(queryData.video);  
rs.pipe(response);
response.end();
```

What's i am missing in the new version?

Comment: Try removing the `response.end()`

Comment: @robertklep Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as robertklep suggested, i removed response.end(). Then it's working